# Javascript eval() adding extra decimal places

Tags: javascript

While doing calculation like this in JavaScript

```
eval(255.792+10)
```

the output I am getting is

```
265.79200000000003
```

but the output I should get is

```
265.792
```

How can I remove those extra decimal places in JavaScript?

Comment: May I ask why you're using `eval` at all?

Comment: _"How can I remove those extra decimal places in JavaScript?"_ [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: because i am doing multiple calculation at once like eval((23.4/3+1)*2.344 +1000) something like this

Comment: Perhaps [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) or [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) depending on your output requirements. Note: it won't be a number; it will be a string.

Comment: @RAHULBISHT That ("doing multiple calculations") has absolutely nothing to do with the actual purpose of `eval()` in JS. You do not need to use `eval()` here, and generally speakng, [_no-one ever needs to use `eval()`, **ever**, at all_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

Comment: i am passing this expression as a string that is why i am using eval

Comment: The code you put in your post doesn't show you using any `string` values.

Comment: For mathemetical expression parsing, you should use a peer-reviewed expression evaluation library (like `mathjs` and not `eval` - even if we disregard the _massive_ security hole that `eval()` creates, because it goes through JS's own [horribly illogical and inconsistent expression rules](https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs) it means that `eval()` is **not** a suitable way to evaluate mathematical expressions.